# How to prevent named grid area blowout when using grid-template-areas?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I have a simple page layout with a side section and a main section. I want my main section to be 3x the side section so I specified a template for areas like so:

```
grid-template-areas: "side main main main";
```

However the side section is growing way larger than expected, making the main section very small.

Expected behavior:
[image]

Actual behavior:
[image]

Here's the code:

```css
.page-layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "side main main main";
}

.main-section {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  grid-area: main;
}

.side-section {
  background-color: orange;
  grid-area: side;
}

.side-layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(min-content, max-content);
  grid-template-areas: "name" "summary" "summary";
}

.name-section {
  grid-area: name;
}

.summary-section {
  grid-area: summary;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-layout">
  <div class="side-section side-layout">
    <h2 class="name">
      Side section
    </h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus blanditiis enim eveniet fugiat impedit laboriosam laudantium magni, maxime, molestiae nemo provident repudiandae.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="main-section">
    <h2>Main section</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I did read this [Preventing a Grid Blowout](https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/) article, but in that article they are using constant pixel value for one of the columns, which will not work for me. I want the main section to be 3x the side section, without specifying a constant pixel size for either of the sections.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't define areas, define sizes using the `fr` unit

```css
.page-layout {
  display: grid;
  /*grid-template-areas: "side main main main";*/
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr
}

.main-section {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.side-section {
  background-color: orange;
}

.side-layout {
  display: grid;
  /*
   not need since you want the content to define the height
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(min-content, max-content);
  grid-template-areas: "name" "summary" "summary";*/
}
```

```html
<div class="page-layout">
  <div class="side-section side-layout">
    <h2 class="name">
      Side section
    </h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus blanditiis enim eveniet fugiat impedit laboriosam laudantium magni, maxime, molestiae nemo provident repudiandae.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="main-section">
    <h2>Main section</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm looking for a solution with `grid-template-areas`.

Also I need to specify `grid-auto-rows` and `grid-template-areas` for `.side-layout` because I doesn't want it to be forced to grow vertically with the same height as main section (my main section will have many paragraphs and the grid items in side section will be stretched vertically).

Comment: @AriaPahlavan sorry but that's not how grid-areas works. You need to specify the size of column with or without grid areas and if you specify the size, grid area can be omitted like demonstrated

Comment: The W3 spec suggests otherwise: "a column is created for each cell in the string". Also "EXAMPLE 20" in the spec creates a similar grid layout without specifying any size.
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-template-areas-property

Comment: @AriaPahlavan a *column* is created but what is its size? it's auto. You have created 4 columns, that's all. To control their size you need to specify the size and to do this you have to use grid-template-columns (or grid-auto-columns). I know that Spec very well, continue the reading to understand how sizing is specified

Comment: @AriaPahlavan "Any rows/columns defined by grid-template-areas but not sized by grid-template-rows/grid-template-columns take their size from the grid-auto-rows/grid-auto-columns properties. If these properties don’t define any explicit tracks the explicit grid still contains one grid line in each axis." https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#explicit-grids

Comment: @AriaPahlavan "intial value: auto" https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#auto-tracks

Comment: @AriaPahlavan https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#track-sizing --> **Explicit** Track Sizing

Comment: Exactly, the initial value of auth, so this issue is happening because the grid item content is large and `auto` is not helping.